# How to type a function that can take and return arrays of strings or arrays of objects?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a directive that in Input can get array of string or array of objects. The directive is to filter the list from `@Input()` and emit a new list in `@Output()`. Inside the directive, I created a method that does all the magic, but I can't correctly type `@Input()` and the function itself.

```
export class SelectFilteringDirective<T> {
  @Input() readonly optionsList: T[] = [];
  @Output() filteredList = new EventEmitter<T[]>();

  constructor() {}

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
  onKeyup(event: Event): void {
    this.filteredList.emit(
      this.filterList(
        this.optionsList,
        (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value
      )
    );
  }

  private filterList(data: T[], value: string): any {
    return typeof data[0] === 'object'
      ? [...data].filter(
          (item) => item.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) != -1
        )
      : [...data].filter(
          (item) => item.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) != -1
        );
  }
}
```

In the variant with the object I get the error:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'T'.
```

However, in the variant with array of strings, I get the error:

```
Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'T'.
```

Comment: btw, you might want to use `data: readonly T[]` as you aren't mutating `data`.

Comment: Where is `T` defined? How is your code even compiling? Please post a reproduction in TypeScript playground.

Comment: Why not have two separate functions: `filterStrings` and `filterObjects`?

Comment: Where are you instantiating `SelectFilteringDirective` ? Also, you _need_ to initialize `optionsList` inline or in the constructor, otherwise it's `undefined` at runtime. I suggest you enable all `strict` options in your tsconfig.

Comment: ```<input matInput selectFiltering [optionsList]="example" (filteredList)="filteredExample = $event">```
if I create two inputs I also have to create two outputs .. I prefer to have one input and output

Comment: It's moot because you can't specify generic type arguments in Angular component HTML.

Comment: Using `toLowerCase()` like that is not an efficient way of filtering strings... Also, **never use** `any`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, you have a directive that receives **one** `@Input` which can be either an `Array` of strings or an `Array` of objects. Based on that, here's a solution for this:

```
type KeyValue = Readonly<{
  key: string;
  value: string;
}>;
type ListItem = string | KeyValue;

@Directive({ selector: 'selectFiltering' })
export class SelectFilteringDirective {
  @Input() optionsList: readonly ListItem[] = [];
  @Output() readonly filteredList = new EventEmitter<ListItem[]>();

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
  onKeyup(event: Event): void {
    this.filteredList.emit(
      this.filterList(
        this.optionsList,
        (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value,
      )
    );
  }

  private filterList(
    list: readonly ListItem[],
    value: string
  ): ListItem[] {
    const lowerCasedValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return list.filter((item) =>
      (typeof item === 'string' ? item : item.value)
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(lowerCasedValue)
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Tip**:

While this might solve the problem, I'm not too sure `@Directive` would be the most correct way to do this. Again, if I got your question correctly, you have some options and you want to filter them out based on input changes... if that's the case, I'd suggest to use a `@Pipe` (pure, ofc) instead.

Just in case you want to see the `@Pipe` version, here you go:

[DEMO using `@Pipe`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-l7nslj)

Comment: This is the solution I expected :D but I got an error in html: ```The type 'readonly string[]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'string[]'.``` code: ```<input matInput selectFiltering [optionsList]="example" (filteredList)="filteredExample = $event">```

Comment: Check the updated version :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the input type like so:

```
@Input() variantOne: string[];
@Input() variantTwo: {key: string, value: string}[]; // although an interface would be better
```

Comment: I want to do it in one Input, by the way, I would like to learn how to create generics or unions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any generics.

Change your code to this:

```
interface Item {
    readonly value: string;
}

type StringsOrObjectsArray = readonly String[] | readonly Item[];

function isItem( x: unknown ): x is Item {
    const whatIf = x as Item;
    return (
        typeof whatIf === 'object' &&
        whatIf !== null &&
        typeof whatIf.value === 'string'
    );
}

//

export class SelectFilteringDirective {

  @Input()  optionsList: StringsOrObjectsArray = [];
  @Output() filteredList                       = new EventEmitter<StringsOrObjectsArray>();

  constructor() {
  }

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
  onKeyup(event: KeyboardEvent): void {

    const inputValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    const oldList    = this.optionsList;
    const newList    = this.filterList( oldList, inputValue );

    this.filteredList.emit( newList );
  }

  private filterList(data: StringsOrObjectsArray, value: string): StringsOrObjectsArray {

    // Preconditions: (defensive-programming is essential in JS and TS!)
    if( !Array.isArray( data ) ) throw new Error( "Expected an array." );
    if( data.length < 1 ) throw new Error( "Expected a non-empty array." );

    const valuePattern = new RegExp( escapeRegExp( value ), 'i' );

    if( typeof data[0] === 'string' ) {

        return data.filter( str => valuePattern.test( str ) );
    }
    else if( isItem( data[0] ) ) {
        // The `isItem` type-guard is unnecessary as TypeScript *should* infer that `data` is `readonly Item[]` here.
        return data.filter( obj => valuePattern.test( obj.value ) );
    }
    else {
        throw new Error( "Unexpected array contents." );
    }
}


function escapeRegExp(str: string): string {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping
  return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
}
```